# Parse.com Android passing multiple parameters to CloudCode function with ParseCloud

Tags: android, parse-platform

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to pass multiple parameters through ParseCloud (Android).

```
ParseCloud.callFunction("functionName", parameter);
```

I'm not sure how to create the HashMap so that it passes request.params.channel and request.params.userId.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hashmaps are used for storing key/value pairs. Assuming ur channel and userId are strings, u can use something like this

```
Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<String, String>();
parameters.put("channel", request.params.channel);
parameters.put("userId", request.params.userId);
```

then call ur function passing in the parametes map.

Comment: I was trying to make HashMap more complicated than it needed to be.  Thank you for the help